# Activiti CDI / Weld SE / CDI unit

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, activiti, cdi-unit

Has anyone ever tried to test Activiti / BPMN processes using pure CDI? In theory (if I didn't miss anything) I would think it should be possible to use f.ex. [cdi-unit](http://jglue.org/cdi-unit/) for testing processes together with activiti-engine and activiti-cdi. CDI unit internally uses weld-se.

But I couldn't make it work, I think the reason is that Activiti CDI and CDI unit work on different contexts, and I haven't found out how to "join" them (or maybe it's not possible).

Using @Inject on a ProcessEngine in a test annotated with @RunWith(CdiRunner.class) (as [in the CDI unit quickstart](http://jglue.org/cdi-unit-user-guide/)) didn't "trigger" anything - i.e. Activiti or the ProcessEngine weren't touched.

Comment: Maybe Arquillian using Weld-EE is the better choice. (http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/) which is already mature project that will help you to run your tests inside CDI container. There are also plenty of extensions and one of them is [camunda](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples) which can help you with testing BPMN processes so maybe you should take look at it :)

Comment: Yes, I've thought about using Arquillian... maybe that's the best choice at the moment. My goal was to stay as lightweight as possible. Isn't Camunda even a fork of Activiti? Are you a contributor? ;-) I'll have a look at it!

Comment: Yes, it's a fork so the extension is hopefully compatible with the Activity. However I am not contributor to it (I used to be to the Arquillian directly while ago) so I can't 100% confirm.